# Largest palindrome product - C#

Tags: c#

Hello fellow programmers

I'm currently trying to solve some problems on Project Euler in C# to improve my knowledge.
However, one solution I made for [Problem #4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) isn't working even though it should.

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Any ideas?

```
    namespace ProjectEuler_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--)
                {
                    if (isPalindome(i *j) == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Digit1: " + i);
                        Console.WriteLine("Digit2: " + j);
                        Console.WriteLine("Outcome: " + i * j);
                          Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j + " =nope");

                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static bool isPalindome(int num)
        {
            string sNum = num.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < sNum.Length / 2; i++)
                if (sNum[i] != sNum[sNum.Length - 1 - i]) return false;

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Outcome is :

Digit1: 995
Digit2: 583
Total: 580085

Though, that is not the right answer.
Anything I did wrong?
I'm not asking for a finished solution, just want to understand what the problem is with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking all combinations. For example, 994 * 994 is larger, and you didn't even check it.

Comment: I did, it's starting from 999*999 then 999*998 ect.

Comment: @Kimo134: Yes, that's the problem, you go (999,999) to (999,1), then (998,999) to (998,1) etc., down to (995,583), and then stop. Check all combinations, find the answer, then think about improving your algorithm, if you want.

Comment: @Kimo134 The first palindrome found using your looping setup isn't necessarily the largest that's going to be found. If you want to brute force the solution, you have to actually use brute force.

Answer (score 2):

Your program actually works and finds the right answer. However, it doesn't print the biggest number first, it's the third output instead.

For example, i=999 j=2 comes before i=998 j=998, but the second product is much bigger. See, you don't find the products in descending order.

The good solution is a simple max-finding loop (kinda-pseudo-code):

```
var best = -1;
for (i, j) {
  if (isPalindrome(i*j) && i*j > best) {
    best = i*j;
  }
}
Console.WriteLine(best);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few notes:

- It's better to start the inner loop from `i`.
- We are able to leave the inner loop if a palindrome has been found, because it's guaranteed that for the current `i` there is no numbers greater than `number`.
- It makes sense to search for the multiplicands that gives the biggest product in the range `99..9 - 90..0`, because they are definitely exist in this range.
- The fastest condition should be the first in the `if` statement.
- I've used a `long` type for variables to make the code below work for bigger numbers.

Try this code sample:

```
// Store the maximum palindrome number here:
long maxNumber = 0;

// The maximum multiplicand (typically: 9...9):
const int NMax = 999;
// The minimum multiplicand.
// Obviously, it couldn't be less than 90...0:
const int NMin = NMax - (NMax + 1) / 10 + 1;

for (int i = NMax; i > NMin; i--)
{
    // Starting from i since i * j = j * i for any i, j:
    for (int j = i; j > NMin; j--)
    {
        long number = Math.BigMul(i, j);
        // The fastest condition should be the first in the `if` statement:
        if (number > maxNumber && isPalindome(number))
        {
            maxNumber = number;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} * {2}", number, i, j);
            break; // Leave the `j` loop, because it's guaranteed that there is
                   // no numbers greater than `number` for the current `i`
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
for NMax=999:     906609 = 993 * 913
for NMax=9999:    99000099 = 9999 * 9901
for NMax=9999999: 99956644665999 = 9998017 * 9997647
```