# Can someone explain how Dmitry got the NMin math down?

Tags: c#, performance, math

The original problem is located at [Project Euler Largest palindrome product](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) and is below.

> **A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99. Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.**

The question in context is found at
[Dmitry Answering Largest palindrome product - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205991/15147831). I got the correct answer but did it from min to max instead of max to min so I looked for a more efficient answer to study. I understand what all the code does, but I can't figure out where [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878550/dmitry) started to get the formula to get the minimum multiplicand from the maximum multiplicand constant. I'm blitzing through several coding challenge websites in preparation for some technical interviews.

This line:

```cs
const int NMin = NMax - (NMax + 1) / 10 + 1;
```

**OF**

```
// Store the maximum palindrome number here:
long maxNumber = 0;

// The maximum multiplicand (typically: 9...9):
const int NMax = 999;
// The minimum multiplicand.
// Obviously, it couldn't be less than 90...0:
const int NMin = NMax - (NMax + 1) / 10 + 1;

for (int i = NMax; i > NMin; i--)
{
    // Starting from i since i * j = j * i for any i, j:
    for (int j = i; j > NMin; j--)
    {
        long number = Math.BigMul(i, j);
        // The fastest condition should be the first in the `if` statement:
        if (number > maxNumber && isPalindome(number))
        {
            maxNumber = number;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} * {2}", number, i, j);
            break; // Leave the `j` loop, because it's guaranteed that there is
                   // no numbers greater than `number` for the current `i`
        }
    }
}
```

The websites I've been going through include:

- [Advent Of Code](https://adventofcode.com/)
- [HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/) and [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/)
- [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/) I've been attempting to finish the [Comprehensive Study Plans](https://leetcode.com/study-plan/)
- [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) Only on Problem #4 right now

Comment: FYI, this might be better suited for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is it worth enumerating i*j in descending order with an approach like https://localcoder.org/efficient-sorted-cartesian-product-of-2-sorted-array-of-integers ?

Comment: And obviously, `if (number < maxNumber) break;` there's no point checking any smaller `j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) the largest palindrome for the product of two-digit numbers is `91*99`. I believe Dmitry recognized that of all max palindromes for a given digit range (3, 4, or 5 as he calculated but realistically to infinity) must be `9x -> 9y` (where `x` represents 0's and `y` represents 9's). The amount of `x` and `y` needed is `digit - 1` if you always want **the highest palindrome.** The lower 90% here is simply not worth checking for palindromes because they won't produce the highest multiplication.

Thus he can calculate the minimum every time given the equation he provided:

```
NMin = NMax - (NMax + 1) / 10 + 1 // NMin = 900 if NMax = 999
```

In the case of 4-digit palindrome, this produces `9,000 -> 9,999` or `90,000 -> 99,999` for 5.

The important thing to note here is he *could* have hard-coded `NMin` or picked a larger minimum number.